# DaisyUI loading twice in terminal

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, npm-package, npm-run, daisyui

I am using Svelkit and DaisyUI

When I do a 'npm run dev' in VS CODE the response in the terminal shows DaisyUI "twice".

```
      ➜  Network: use --host to expose

 � daisyUI components 2.24.0  https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui
   ✔︎ Including:  base, components, themes[1], utilities
 
 � daisyUI components 2.24.0  https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui
   ✔︎ Including:  base, components, themes[1], utilities
 
 {
   name: 'Home',
   component: { render: [Function: render], '$$render': [Function: $$render] }
 }
```

> [Here is an image of my terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaCWN.png)

Please let me know if this is normal, why it happens or if this happens because I made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: I'm having same issue, have you found something?

Comment: No, I didn't. I ended up removing daisy UI ...

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui/issues/300